# Column sorting issue in date field with dd/MM/YYYY format in angular ig-grid

Tags: angular-grid, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

In igx-grid,

1. When we apply sorting in ascending and descending order with dd-mm-yyyy format, so sorting is not working with actual date, month and year wise. and only apply date wise sorting.
2. When we apply sorting in ascending and descending order the date filed it is sorted by yyyy-mm-dd format and we display date in dd/MM/yyyy format on UI using pipe. So sorting is not working in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't applied `[dataType]="'date'"` to the grid column, then the type defaults to `string` and column values will be sorted as strings. Add the correct `dataType` and sorting will work on the dates, regardless of formatting.